# Blank screen on start, URL loads correctly in Chrome

Tags: cefsharp

I am using CEfSharp v45.0.0.0 in a WinForm. It's platform is x86. The form loads with its menu, but the target url doesn't load, no error just blank. The app works on other computers. I have the following CefCommandLineArgs set

disable-web-security
enable-media-stream
disable-gpu

When I open the debugger it is blank as well. There is only the controlbox and the minimize, restore and close icons.

No errors are getting logged.

I am not sure what to try next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you upgrade to a supported version?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing,  make sure you've installed VC++ that matches the version you are using https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#release-branches

Comment: Thanks, I'll upgrade and see how I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version fixed the problem.